# FindFit with parameters which are simultaneously in initial conditions

Tags: differential-equations, fitting

I have RLC circuit. I would like to find R and L by using FindFit, but L is in initial condition and I have problem with it. Could you help me ?

```
c = 116*10^(-6); U = 16000. ; 

data = 
{
   {0, 0}, {0.25*10^(-6), 132000}, {0.5*10^(-6), 330000}, {1*10^(-6), 462000}, 
   {2*10^(-6), 600000}, {3*10^(-6), 462000}, {4*10^(-6), 330000}, {5*10^(-6), 66000}, 
   {6*10^(-6), -198000}, {7*10^(-6), -264000}, {8*10^(-6), -198000}, {9*10^(-6), -132000}
};

lp = ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]

fit = 
  FindFit[data,
    First[i /. 
      NDSolve[{i''[t] + R/L * i'[t] + 1/(c L)*i[t] == 0, i[0] == 0, i'[0] == U/L}, 
        i, {t, 0, 9*10^(-6)}]],
    {{R, 10*10^(-3)}, {L, 20*10^(-9)}}, 
    i, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 4, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 4]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your set up:

```
c = 116*10^(-6); U = 16000;

data = {{0, 0}, {0.25*10^(-6), 132000}, {0.5*10^(-6), 
    330000}, {1*10^(-6), 462000}, {2*10^(-6), 600000}, {3*10^(-6), 
    462000}, {4*10^(-6), 330000}, {5*10^(-6), 
    66000}, {6*10^(-6), -198000}, {7*10^(-6), -264000}, {8*10^(-6), \
-198000}, {9*10^(-6), -132000}};
```

Use **analytic not numerical form DSolve**:

```
model = (i /. 
     DSolve[{i''[t] + R/L*i'[t] + 1/(c L)*i[t] == 0, i[0] == 0, 
       i'[0] == U/L}, i, {t, 0, 9*10^(-6)}])[[1, 2]];
model // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Find a fit:

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {{R, 10*10^(-3)}, {L, 20*10^(-9)}}, t];
fit["BestFitParameters"]
```

> {R -> 0.0109553, L -> 2.15996*10^-8}

```
Show[ListPlot[data], 
 Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 9 10^-6}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]], 
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for help. What if we treat equation as without analytical solution ?

Comment: @Krzysiek In such case I would try using `ParametricNDSolve` - look through the examples [HERE](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html) to grasp the scope.